# Using a user defined class vector inside the class file

Tags: c++, class, vector, member-functions

I have a class called Account with below parameters:

```
Account::Account(string ibanCode, string paramOwner, double amount) {}
```

I have created a vector consisting of class Accounts inside main function:

```
accs.push_back(Account(fullName, iban, value));
```

I want to write a function to print all the Account values in my vector by a class member function called displayAll() , and so far I tried this:

```
void Account::displayAll() 
{

  for (int i = 0; i < accs.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << accs[i].displayBalance() << endl;;
  }
}
```

And I want to write it inside the class file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you want `Account` to know about all accounts, try making `accs` a `static` member of `Account` instead of a local variable in the main function.

Comment: Managing such a static vector would be a mess. Just make `displayAll` a free function, not a class member, which takes vector as input argument: `void displayAll(const std::vector<Account>& accs){/*body stays the same*/}`

Comment: Think about what you're asking, you have a class, and you fill a vector with objects of this class, but you want an object inside the container to print the whole content of the container, this is terrible design, and there is no elegant solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making it a member would be extremely complicated, the best option should be using a normal function that can access the parameters.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Account {
        Account (string ibanCode, string paramOwner, double amount) : _amount(amount), _ibanCode(ibanCode), _paramOwner(paramOwner) {};
        string _ibanCode;
        string _paramOwner;
        double _amount;
    };
    
    void DisplayAll (const vector<Account>& Accs) {
        for (const auto& Acc : Accs) {
            cout << Acc._ibanCode<<' '<<Acc._paramOwner<<' '<< Acc._amount<<'\n';
        }
        return;
    }
    
    int main () {
        vector<Account> Accs;
        Accs.push_back(Account("SomeCode", "SomeOwner", 2.0));
        Accs.push_back(Account("SomeOtherCode", "SomeOtherOwner", 3000.42));
        DisplayAll(Accs);
    }
```

To avoid complicating the answer too much I made a struct but you can either make the `DisplayAll` function a `friend` of the class or make some getters.